# Manual pagination with DynamoDBMapper?

Tags: java, angular, pagination, amazon-dynamodb

I have a Java web application making use of [DynamoDBMapper](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.html) for easier data persistence within DynamoDB.  In one use case I have a very large number of items that I would like to be able to paginate through manually in an Angular web app.  However, I've come across numerous documents that talk about DynamoDBMapper's support for automatic pagination ([see here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/understanding-auto-paginated-scan-with-dynamodbmapper/)) wherein results are lazy-loaded on an as-needed basis.

Is there a way to paginate through my results *manually*?  That is, I'd like to specify a start value (either an index or last-loaded key) and retrieve a maximum number of results so that I can paginate on my own terms.  I haven't been able to find any documentation outlining how to do this.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

When you get a [QueryResultPage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/QueryResultPage.html) or [ScanResultPage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/mobileconnectors/dynamodbv2/dynamodbmapper/ScanResultPage.html) you get back `getLastEvaluatedKey`.

> Returns the last evaluated key, which can be used as the exclusiveStartKey to fetch the next page of results. Returns null if this is the last page of results.

So you can use `getLastEvaluatedKey` to manually page.

Something to note is that Dynamodb only returns the key for the current page, meaning all you can do is go to the next page. You can't, for example, know how many pages you have before starting to page, or skip to an arbitrary page number without iterating through each page to get there.